# Cannot open skype custom URL from android WebView

Tags: android, webview, skype, custom-url

I'm currently developing an application with android WebView.

However, the website has a link that will invoke Skype application.

The link work fine when try with Chrome browser on android, but it return an error when try to open in android WebView. Actually, it gave me an Webpage not Available error.

Any advice?

Regards.

Answer (score 3):

You should check the url that is click/opened in the webview and check if there is an application that handles this kind of urls:

```
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

        if (url == skype url) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(intent);
       } else {
            view.loadUrl(url);
       }
       return true;
    }
});
```